# merge in oracle updating value but not inserting, neither giving error version 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-merge

Update is working fine but insert is not giving any error neither it is inserting unable to understand the issue.

Its single table in which I want to insert/update values

```
  MERGE INTO SOFT_FILENAME A
  USING (select TC, TC_DT, LASTNO
           FROM SOFT_FILENAME
          where TC = 'KMB'
            AND to_date(tc_dt,'dd-mon-yyyy') = to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy')) B
  ON ( A.TC = 'KMB'  AND to_date(A.tc_dt,'dd-mon-yyyy') = to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy') AND A.TC_DT = B.TC_DT AND A.TC = B.TC)

  when matched then

    UPDATE
       SET A.LASTNO = A.LASTNO + 1
     WHERE A.TC = 'KMB'
       AND to_date(A.tc_dt,'dd-mon-yyyy') = to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy')


  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

    INSERT (A.TC, A.TC_DT, A.LASTNO) VALUES ('KMB', to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy'), 1);
```

Table script

```
create table A
(
  TC     CHAR(3),
  TC_DT  DATE,
  LASTNO NUMBER(6)
)
```

Alternate way to achieve this using procedure is following way but I don't want to call procedure.
Following is what I want to achieve using merge.

```
begin
  select count(1)
    into cou  
    FROM SOFT_FILENAME
   where TC = V_TC
     AND to_date(tc_dt, 'dd-mon-yyyy') = to_date(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy');
  if (cou = 0) then
    INSERT into SOFT_FILENAME A
      (A.TC, A.TC_DT, A.LASTNO)
    VALUES
      (V_TC, sysdate, 1);
  else
    UPDATE SOFT_FILENAME A
       SET A.LASTNO = A.LASTNO + 1
     WHERE A.TC = V_TC
       AND
       to_date(A.tc_dt, 'dd-mon-yyyy') =
           to_date(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy'); 
  end if;
end
```

Comment: Is the problem, that you see no record with `LASTNO = 1` ? Check the `INSERT` statement, you set it to `10` - typo??

Comment: That is fine there are no constraint on table you can write it as 1 or 10, I am just inserting a record with no condition if it does not exists. My table is empty as of now

Comment: As an aside, if tc_dt is of data type DATE (and it _should_ be) then you are comparing a DATE (tc_dt) to a _string_ representation of a DATE.  This forces oracle to do an implied to_date, using the controlling setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  You are lucky it works at all. Plus you are ignoring the 20-year old lessons of Y2k.  You should replace all occurrences of "18-apr-20' with "to_date('18-apr-2020','dd-mon-yyyy')"

Comment: What do you mean by "A and C both are same tables"? they have the same data? If yes, then no insert will be done, only updates

Comment: Replaced with actual query which I am using

Comment: Well this explains all - you **can not see NOT-matching rows in one and the same table**.  The question is *what you want to achieve*, while merging A into A?

Comment: Its simple I am checking the lastno of data against column tc on system date. This is counter table if data is inserted in another table. So at start of day for 1st record it check if data is present, if yes then update else insert.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output. Note also that the part `to_date(tc_dt,'dd-mon-yyyy') = to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy')` ist not correct `sysdate` **is** a DATE format - no need to convert it to date. It work only *by accident* for your NLS setting. Try to formulate what you want to achieve - will not be a *simple UPDATE of the column LASTNO* good enough?

Comment: to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy') I need to pass this as default sysdate returns time along with date as well which I don't want to compare as it would never return me any value.

Comment: `to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy')` is a **very bad** way to get rid of the time component of the `sysdate` as you rely on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. Usually is used `trunc(sydate)`